# Reading input in kotlin using generate sequence

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, terminal

I'm a newbie in kotlin.

I was running the below code to understand how BigDecimal works, but i'm missing something on how to safely exit from intellij terminal after entering the input. I always get `NumberFormatException` if i don't enter anything and press Enter key. How to quit safely and see the result.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = generateSequence { readLine() }
    println(input
        .map { it.toBigDecimal() }
        .fold(0.toBigDecimal()) { a, b -> a + b })
}
```

Source
https://medium.com/@elizarov/floating-point-for-decimals-fc2861898455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> after input

Comment: …which will send end-of-file, cause readLine() to return null, and end the sequence.

Comment: ( Cmd + d ) in mac